# Track a smartphone in 3D space with an outside source tracking.

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

unsure if this questions is right for this site, but anyway...

In few months I'll be beginning my Uni dissertation and I have a few ideas, some revolve around tracking the position of a smartphone in 3D space, I'm wondering if there is any way to do this.

I believe there is no way to do this solely with the phone and its' gyroscope and accelerometer, even though I feel it might be possible. I am expecting the best case will be to use 1-3 Raspberry Pi and hopefully apply something to them which will enable them to track the phone in 3D space.

Ideally I'd like something which can get precise readings of the phones' movements, even through objects such as a TV screen or even a wall, but to simply get the phones location in space as a blank dot. I'm not sure of any signals smartphones emit, or one the external 1-3 raspberry Pis could give out which could be used to precisely triangulate it's position, but I feel its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about "tracking with an outside source" but you later reference it's internal sensors like you will have access to them. You also reference a signal it might emit that you could measure and track.

Tracking in 3D space requires a reference point (a known location) and then coordinates indicating the object position relative to that point (called "triangulation" by most people). Cell towers have enough data to triangulate position based on their constant collection of the phone's cellular radio signal and the ability for several known locations to collect that data. So, is it possible? Absolutely and they do it all the time. Look up "cell tower hand off" or "handover" for more information. However, in most situations you will not have access to all of this data and several known locations to make appropriate determinations. Also, they typically don't need very fine location data (less than a meter), so it isn't necessarily helpful to you. Maybe a good dissertation though...

Most other signals produced by the device (e.g.. bluetooth, wifi) use much shorter wavelengths (higher frequency) and are subject to much more interference caused by objects like walls to use for exact triangulation purposes. However, it seems like that might make a good dissertation, since that's what you're interested in doing. It's heavy on signal processing and it may not even be possible. Further reading here:

http://www.networkworld.com/article/2170751/tech-primers/location-based-wi-fi-services-can-add-immediate-value-to-wi-fi-deployments.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_spectrum

So, if we assume access to sensors, it helps. However, you still need "known locations" because sensor data is subject to error. And as the device moves and reports information about how it is moving, small errors turn into big ones. Think about shooting a laser across a room vs. across a city. Again, not a bad concept for a dissertation wherein you might spend the time and energy collecting various sensor data in order to reduce the impact of the error on location calculations.

*EDIT*

Signal timing is radar and the devices probably are precise enough, but maybe you could find a way. Signal strength is what is used currently. Roughly it's like this - Station A measures the device signal at "X". Station B measures the same signal at "1/8 of X". Because signal strength is typically a cube root function, you might assume Station B is twice as far from the signal as Station A. If you add another station, you could triangulate the position - if it were a perfect world. However, the phone might be in the person's pocket while they are standing next to Station B. How would you know? You need several stations. Also, if the phone is next to a surface that reflects it's signal back to Station A, it may "appear" to be closer if the reflection occurs just right.

We haven't even covered things like station calibration (how do we know the signal is "1/8" strength at B compared to A?), determining the actual location of each station, doing real-time signal processing and other types of interference.

I don't do this kind of work. I did some signal processing a long time ago, so this is just high-level stuff that I find interesting. You should also look at this (in case you weren't aware):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon

Comment: This is really helpful, I did a quick MS Paint masterpiece to illustrate my idea: http://i.imgur.com/2vXjdRZ.png To have the phones' bluetooth signal received by 3 receivers that will be able to know the  time it took the signal to reach each of them, and then be able to figure out the distance. Or as you mentioned with Wi-Fi and bluetooth being more prone to interference and the time difference being fractions of a millisecond if it'd be far too inacurate.

Comment: I edited my comment. I thought it would be too much to fit in here.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  I am probably just narrowing down the field of options suggested by Jim, but Android does have a WiFi manager class.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html , which seems to have methods for calculating and comparing signal strengths.  I would say with a sufficient number of cheap wifi routers/access points at known locations, and a little bit if math this would be very doable, not to mention fun. It almost seems too easy, but if you have to factor in some sort of calibration of the strength of each access point, etc,, it might make a good dissertation.

Comment: I like you're idea, and I'm for sure going to try this, like right now! +1